# How to refactor switch statement in JSX

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, refactoring, jsx

How would I refactor the following switch statement in my JSX, as you can see it is DRY. I need to render `2 buttons(awake & asleep)` if case is `C` or `TV`. Render `a button(View room)` if the case if `IB` and render `not applicable` if case is `OL`

```
const PatientRow = ({patientInfo, patientStatus}) => {

return (
        <tbody>
            {patientInfo.map((patient, index) =>
                <tr key={patient.name} >
                    <td>{patient.room}</td>
                    <td>{patient.name}</td>
                    <td>{patient.obsLevel}</td>
                    <td>{patient.roomStatus}</td>
                    <td>{patient.obsDue}</td>

<td>
 {(() => {
               switch (patient.locationInfo) {
                     case 'IB': return 
<Button id="View Room" onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}> View Room </Button>;

                     case 'C': return <div> 
<Button id="Awake"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}> Awake </Button> <Button id="Asleep"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}>Asleep</Button></div>;

                     case 'TV': return <div> <Button id="Awake"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}> Awake </Button> <Button id="Asleep"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}>Asleep</Button></div>;

                     case 'OL': return <p> not applicable </p>;
                                default: return '';
                            }
                        })()}
</td>

}
```

```
this.state={
     statusBtn: ['Awake', 'Asleep']
     patientInfo: [
                   {room: 1, locationInfo: '', status: ''},
                   {room: 2, locationInfo: ''},
                   {room: 3, locationInfo: ''},
                   {room: 4, locationInfo: ''},
                   {room: 5, locationInfo: ''},
                   {room: 7, locationInfo: ''}
                ],
}
```

Comment: move it to a function defined within your component and call if from JSX

Comment: @HunterMcMillen ok that helps but is there a clever way to map over the statusBtn and pass the` {onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}}` to it further cleans my code

Comment: @Jose I wrote a react library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-floco that you might find useful should you need to render through switch statements in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fall-through

```
 {(() => {
               switch (patient.locationInfo) {

                     case 'IB': return 
<Button id="View Room" onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}> View Room </Button>;
                     case 'C': // case 'C' should fall-through to case 'TV'

                     case 'TV': return <div> <Button id="Awake"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}> Awake </Button> <Button id="Asleep"
                                    onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index)}>Asleep</Button></div>;

                     case 'OL': return <p> not applicable </p>;
                                default: return '';
                            }
                        })()}
```

but definitely always leave a comment whenever you decide to fall-through in a switch case.

By the way, you can also refactor the inline click handler function away:

```
 {(() => {
               const handleClick = (e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index);
               switch (patient.locationInfo) {

                     case 'IB': return 
<Button id="View Room" onClick={handleClick}> View Room </Button>;

                     case 'C': // case 'C' should fall-through to case 'TV'

                     case 'TV': return <div> <Button id="Awake"
                                    onClick={handleClick}> Awake </Button> <Button id="Asleep"
                                    onClick={handleClick}>Asleep</Button></div>;

                     case 'OL': return <p> not applicable </p>;
                                default: return '';
                            }
                        })()}
```

You can move it to some other place in your render function:

```
render () {
  ... other code
  const renderButtons = () => {
               const handleClick = (e) => patientStatus(e, patient, index);
               switch (patient.locationInfo) {

                     case 'IB': return 
<Button id="View Room" onClick={handleClick}> View Room </Button>;

                     case 'C': // case 'C' should fall-through to case 'TV'

                     case 'TV': return <div> <Button id="Awake"
                                    onClick={handleClick}> Awake </Button> <Button id="Asleep"
                                    onClick={handleClick}>Asleep</Button></div>;

                     case 'OL': return <p> not applicable </p>;
                                default: return '';
                            }
                        }
    return (
    <tags>
     ....
     {renderButtons()}
    </tags>
    );
}
```